# How to author an Internet protocol?

Tags: networking, protocols

We're all familiar with popular protocols like IMAP and POP, used for email messaging.

I have a plan for a new protocol, but I'm not sure to go about implementing it.

Is the protocol a collection of C source code, for example, that accepts and sends data through ports? Or is a protocol just a thorough description of how data should be sent, which clients then implement?

I'm lost where to start here, and I'm not very familiar with how the protocol system works.

#### Edit:

Also, if I write a protocol and it isn't made official by the standards group, can people/clients still implement it?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments

Comment: So I gather from that, that RFC's are just text documents that outline how protocols work?

Comment: RFC must describe the protocol in enough detail so that it is possible to make (at least) two independent implementations, based solely on the RFC text, that can talk with each other.

Comment: If you write a protocol and it isn't made "official," why the Belgium would anyone *not* still be able to implement it?

Comment: Well I suppose when you lay it out like that... haha.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The official way is to write an [RFC - a Request for Comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Request_for_Comments). People will respond to that (that's why it's an RFC) and probably try to implement your protocol.

As soon as two independent implementations exist that completely support the protocol, it's a new standard.

Of course, people aren't going to implement a new protocol for someone just for fun. So you should first find a group who is interested in listening to you. Maybe there already is a protocol which does what you want (or can easily be extended).

But you probably don't want to invent a new standard. Standards are a lot of work and - for some - overrated.

So you should describe how it works and create a library that can read and write the protocol, so developers can use it even though it's not an official standard.

Comment: +1 from me.I agree with your comments except for one point which I am not sure how you mean it.`Standards are overrated` why?Who says that?

Comment: I'm curious why you commented that "You probably don't want to invent a new standard". The protocol I'm designing is fairly ambitious (it's sort of a re-design of email). But it's also much needed, as evidence by bullet #2 here: http://paulgraham.com/ambitious.html.

Comment: @Archio You may want to re-read the final section of that article and seriously think about whether this is the right way to go about things.  A more likely path to success would be to implement something so the importance of it is more obvious, and allow it to become a standard from there.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing a protocol standard with the implementation.

These 2 are unrelated.
A protocol is described in a high level but has enough information for someone to undestand how it should be implemented.

The idea is that someone reading the document can understand how/what to implement in *any* language of preference

To give an example: SIP protocol in the RFC describes the various flows and also has the various messages and how they are supposed to b processed i.e. the ***semantics*** well defined.

You can implement a SIP UA or Server in C++ or Java. This is irrelevant to the SIP protocol

For this you don't need to provide any source code (you could though if you think it helps clarify some obscurity of the description).

The most important part is that your protocol is actually *reviewed by stakeholders* i.e. people that expect it to solve their problems.
This part is the most important not only because it could solve problems in your protocol but because they can actually verify that the concept is solid i.e. can be technically implemented

The only case that one could specify something concrete or imply something is if for example the protocol described something demanding some specific constraints e.g. hard-real time constraint which could serve as "hint" on which implementation/languages to avoid

> Also, if I write a protocol and it isn't made official by the
>   standards group, can people/clients still implement it?

Strange question.What do you mean?How will someone know your protocol exists?
If it is official he can get it from the standards group to implement it.
Otherwise it is obvious that you have some sort of "proprietary" protocol (which is not uncommon e.g. a company can have an internal protocol for its own software) and people have to get the spec from you.

Answer (score 1):

As you are interested in the [Replace Email](http://paulgraham.com/ambitious.html) section of the Paul Graham article you linked, then IMHO you will need to both develop a protocol definition, and also provide an  example implementation. The protocol definition does not need to be published as an internet protocol standard in order to be useful.

You will need an implementation to so that you can test, refine and improve the ideas. It is extremely unlikely the protocol will be right at the first attempt, and you'll need something to support the initial users.

You don't *need* a protocol definition to implement an improved email, but you will need one if you expect others to work with you and adopt it, though it very much depends on your 'business model'. I strongly recommend you have a protocol definition from the start, even if only to keep yourself sane when you try to produce the second implementation.

I recommend having a look at some examples of sneaky approaches to protocols and implementation. My favourite is described in the [Viewpoints Research 2008 Progress report](http://www.vpri.org/pdf/tr2008004_steps08.pdf) on a super-compact approach to TCP/IP.

They did not follow the traditional approach to developing the implementation of a protocol (the protocol stack). Instead they wrote code which parsed the human-readable TCP/IP protocol specification, and generated the code of a TCP/IP stack from that protocol document. The usual TCP/IP stack is about 40,000 lines of code, or more. Their program, which read the protocol specification, and generated the code for a TCP/IP stack 'automatically' was only 160 lines of code. They use extremly powerful programming tools.

If you had an approach like that, you could keep the protocol implementation synchronised with the specification, and potentially make it straightforward for others to adopt your protocol.

HTH